# hasMany relationship not updating in the database

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I save a Block (which belongs to a Cube), the `belongsTo` relationship is saved but the `hasMany` relationship for the Cube is not. After creating the Block, no PUT request is being sent to the server to update the Cube.

Block Model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  description: DS.attr(),
  cube: DS.belongsTo('cube')
});
```

Cube Model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  description: DS.attr(),
  blocks: DS.hasMany('block', { async: true })
});
```

Saving the Block:

```
  var name = this.get('name');
  var description = this.get('description');
  var cube = this.store.peekRecord('cube', this.model.id);

  if (!name) {return;}

  this.store.createRecord('block', {
    name: name,
    description: description,
    cube: cube
  })
  .save()
  .then(function() {
    this.resetForm();
    var name = slugify(this.model.get('name'));
    this.transitionToRoute('cubes.show', this.model.get('id'), name);
  }
  .bind(this));
```

Comment: instead of `this.model.id` try `this.get('model.id')`. and one more important point is insteadof `.bind(this)`. You can use arrow function like `.then(()=>{ //you can access this reference; })`